# Sublime CodeIntel, adding django path

Tags: python, django, sublimetext2, sublimecodeintel

I'm trying to configure Sumblime CodeIntel so that it works with django. The official docs state that:

> For adding additional library paths (django for example), either add those paths as folders to your project, or create
>   an optional codeintel configuration file in your home or in your
>   project's root.
>
> Configuration files (~/.codeintel/config or
>   project_root/.codeintel/config). All configurations are optional.

I localized and edited the `~/.codeintel/config` file, so that `config` now looks like this(added the bolded part):

```
{
    "Python": {
        **"python": "C:/Python27/django-tom/Lib/site-packages",**
        "pythonExtraPaths": [
            "libs",
            "~/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS",
            "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS",
         ]
     }
}
```

`django-tom is my virtualenv django folder. However the autocompletion is not working for django (but works fine with the rest of python).

Comment: are you running sublime from within your virtual environment?

Comment: No, I only run django within my virtual env

Answer (score 1):

this is how i have it

```
{
"Python": {
    "python": 'path to python/bin/python',
    "pythonExtraPaths": ['path to pytho/python2.7/site-packages/',
    ]
},
```

}

if you're using env you can have hooks with virtualenvwrapper
let me know if you need help on setting that up
also there a sublimeRope package which is python specific

Comment: I installed the Rope, via Package Control. I guess it's expected to be working just after the installation is completed and in my case Sumlime Rope never took off. If you could elaborate on the virtualenvwrapper and how it can get CodeIntel working for django, I'd be grateful.

Comment: for the rope to work you have to make a new rope project. while in your project dir press ctrl+shift+p, and look for ROPE, then just press New Project. it's gonna ask you for project root and the for env root.

Comment: for virtualenvwrapper http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html        and the script for code intel https://gist.github.com/jaysw/3567725    you have to put this code in your postmkvirtualenv.sh